# allowframebreaks in beamer shading box disappear using knitr

Tags: r, knitr, beamer

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\begin{document}
<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(out.lines = 4)
opts_chunk$set(size = 'footnotesize')
options(width=60)
knit_hooks$set(document = function(x) {
gsub('\\\\(begin|end)\\{kframe\\}', '', x)
})
@
```

After I do this, the R source code and output which is supposing to be displayed in a shaded box now disappear. Any idea on how to get the shaded box back?

Comment: well, you do define a hook specifically targeted at removing the `kframe` you don't find in the output...

Comment: @baptiste `kframe` does not work with `allowframebreaks`, and that is the reason why it was removed. I do not have a good solution to keep the shading box while using the `allowframebreaks` option. `render_sweave()` and `render_listings()` will work, though.